# Space between sectioning header and tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing

[image: Space between]

I have this situation on Latex.
How can I eliminate this space between the `\section{PESTA}` and the tabular?

```
\subsection{PEST+A}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}|p{10cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{PEST+A} \\
 \hline
 ...
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please post fully working examples of your code. Your problem is not reproducible - there's no gap over here. Maybe it's because of a missing package? Maybe you want to try to wrap the tabular environment into a table environment and then force it to the position with `\begin{table}[H]`.

Comment: What happens if you insert the instruction `\raggedbottom` immediately before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: What *follows* this table? I'm guessing another table that is fairly large.

Comment: @Mico your solution solves the problem :) Thanks!! Put in the answer ;)

Comment: @PRVS - Glad to know that my suggestion/guess was on target. Per your request, I've re-posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Earlier comment re-posted as an answer.)

It looks like your document uses the `\flushbottom` setting. To change this, insert the instruction

```
\raggedbottom
```

immediately before `\begin{document}`.